# Cross-lagged panel model in lavaan - error says duplicate paths but there are no duplicate paths

Tags: r-lavaan

I'm trying to run a cross-lagged panel model in R. I keep getting the same error, regardless of how simple I make my model or how I alter the order of the variables. I can't see any duplicate model elements but maybe I don't understand what that error means. I'd appreciate any thoughts! I'm pretty new to R and have searched for answers everywhere and can't figure it out!

##ERROR MESSAGE###
Error in lavParseModelString(model) :
lavaan ERROR: duplicate model element in: p_FIavCV~b1*bl_GQ6score+b2*w4_GQ6score+b3*w8_GQ6score+b4*p_GQ6score+b5*TX_Condition

###CODE ###
`model10 <- '

## Cross-lagged paths

p_FIavMP ~ c1* bl_panas_x_p + c2* w4_panas_x_p + c3* w8_panas_x_p + c4* p_panas_x_p + c5* TX_Condition
p_FIavMPH ~ c6* bl_panas_x_p + c7* w4_panas_x_p + c8* w8_panas_x_p + c9* p_panas_x_p + c10* TX_Condition
p_FIavCV ~ c11* bl_panas_x_p + c12* w4_panas_x_p + c13* w8_panas_x_p + c14* p_panas_x_p + c15* TX_Condition
p_FIavHLS ~ c16* bl_panas_x_p + c17* w4_panas_x_p + c18* w8_panas_x_p + c19* p_panas_x_p + c20* TX_Condition

## Mediation paths

bl_GQ6score ~ a1* bl_panas_x_p
w4_GQ6score ~ a2* w4_panas_x_p
w8_GQ6score ~ a3* w8_panas_x_p
p_GQ6score ~ a4* p_panas_x_p

## Direct paths mediators to outcomes

p_FIavCV ~ b1* bl_GQ6score + b2* w4_GQ6score + b3* w8_GQ6score + b4* p_GQ6score + b5* TX_Condition
p_FIavMP ~ b6* bl_GQ6score + b7* w4_GQ6score + b8* w8_GQ6score + b9* p_GQ6score + b10* TX_Condition
p_FIavMPH ~ b11* bl_GQ6score + b12* w4_GQ6score + b13* w8_GQ6score + b14* p_GQ6score + b15* TX_Condition
p_FIavHLS ~ b16* bl_GQ6score + b17* w4_GQ6score + b18* w8_GQ6score + b19* p_GQ6score + b20* TX_Condition

## Covariances between variables

bl_panas_x_p ~~ w4_panas_x_p
bl_panas_x_p ~~ w8_panas_x_p
bl_panas_x_p ~~ p_panas_x_p
w4_panas_x_p ~~ w8_panas_x_p
w4_panas_x_p ~~ p_panas_x_p
w8_panas_x_p ~~ p_panas_x_p
w4_GQ6score ~~ bl_GQ6score
bl_GQ6score ~~ w8_GQ6score
bl_GQ6score ~~ p_GQ6score
w8_GQ6score ~~ w4_GQ6score
p_GQ6score ~~ w8_GQ6score
p_GQ6score ~~ w4_GQ6score
p_FIavCV ~~ p_FIavMP
p_FIavCV ~~ p_FIavMPH
p_FIavCV ~~ p_FIavHLS
p_FIavMP ~~ p_FIavMPH
p_FIavMP ~~ p_FIavHLS
p_FIavHLS ~~ p_FIavMPH
'

## Fit the model

`fit <- sem(model10, data = imputed_data4)`

## Summarize the results

summary(fit)

I tried changing the order of the covariances and I tried simplifying the model to only run the cross-lagged paths and got the same error (in relation to a different variable).